# How to pass control reference to formatter in XMLView?

Tags: sapui5

In SAPUI5's JSView, it is quite easy to pass the current control reference to a formatter function:

```js
oTable.bindItems("/rows", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    cells : [ new sap.m.Text().bindProperty("text", {
        parts: [
            { path: "someInteger" }
        ],
        formatter: function(iValue) { 
            var idText = this.getId(); //this references the current control
            return iValue;
        }
    })]
}));
```

*(The 'easy' part of course is because `this` is referenced in the control's inner formatter function)*

However, with XMLViews I haven't managed yet to get a reference to the current control in the formatter function:

```xml
<Table items="{/rows}">
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Some Integer" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{ path : 'someInteger', formatter : '.formatCell' }" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

And the formatter:

```js
formatCell : function (sValue) {
    var a = this; //this references the controller
    return sValue;
}
```

Anyone knows how to make this work in XMLViews?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have control instance as "this" in formatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290194/how-to-have-control-instance-as-this-in-formatter)

Comment: Sorry, trying to guide other readers [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295695/odatamodel-aggregations-getbindingcontext-returns-undefined#comment86083887_26295695) to (IMHO) better answer :P

Comment: As my original question is almost 5 years old and UI5 has changed significantly over the years, yes, definitely :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your formatter functions in a separate file. Then `this` will be the Control whose property is being formatted.

my/own/Formatter.js:

```js
sap.ui.define(function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        formatCell: function (iValue) {
            var idText = this.getId(); //this references the current control
            return iValue;
        }
    };
});
```

View:

```xml
<Table items="{/rows}">
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Some Integer" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{ path : 'someInteger', formatter : 'my.own.Formatter.formatCell' }" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Comment: I can't get it to work, in the guide it says to include the formatter in the controller and to set ``formatter: Formatter`` in the controller. After that, I can use .formatter in the xml view to call the formatter function. But there it has the view scope, not the scope of the element. Any idea why?

Comment: @MichaelK. The formatter module needs to be exported so that it can be globally referenced by the module name. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54419469/5846045

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @codeworrior in this [issue](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/900) make it more clear:

> A name that starts with a dot (e.g. ".foo") is searched for in the controller of the view and the execution context will be enforced to being the controller.
>
> All other names are resolved starting from the window object and they get the control/element as context which holds the binding.

---

Just complement @hirse's answer, and for those who get `formatter function xxx not found` error:

both `.formatter.myformatter` and `mynamespace.Formatter.myformatter` is working.

The logic of parse formatter is in [sap.ui.base.BindingParser.resolveRef(oBindingInfo,'formatter')](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/f76d2efea1b2099680e0649c19e6024b4ec02876/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/BindingParser.js#L164)

`BindingParser` seems different in [sapUI5(1.54)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/base/BindingParser-dbg.js) and [openUI5](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/f76d2efea1b2099680e0649c19e6024b4ec02876/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/BindingParser.js#L164). I'll take sapUI5 version as an example.

If formatter name starts with a dot ('.'), eg. `.formatter.myformatter`,  lookup will start with the given context(the Controller of the view), otherwise("mynamespace.Formatter.myformatter") it will start with the global context (window).

and `jQuery.sap.getObject("formatter.myformatter", oContext)` or  `jQuery.sap.getObject("mynamespace.Formatter.myformatter", window)` is called.

so If you get `formatter function xxx not found!` error. set a break point in `jQuery.sap.getObject`, and check if there is "myformatter" in oContext or window object.

And I found that there is no `mynamespace.Formatter.myformatter` in my window object. so I change my formatter from

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
  return {
    myformatter: function () {}
  }
})
```

To

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
  var Formatter = {
    myformatter: function () {}
  }
  
  return Formatter
}, /* bExport */ true)
```

And it's working.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. About the "`BindingParser` seems different in  [sapUI5(1.54)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/base/BindingParser-dbg.js) and [openUI5](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/f76d2efea1b2099680e0649c19e6024b4ec02876/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/BindingParser.js#L164)": The latter link shows the nightly version (master branch) which has received several updates since the current stable version (1.54).

Answer (score 0):

Formatter must be defined with variable. Formatter reference must be included in controller. Formatter must be referenced with absolut path.

Formatter.js

```
sap.ui.define([], function () {
var Formatter = {
    myFormatter: function () {
        return "";
    }
}

return Formatter }, /* bExport */ true)
```

View.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
 ...
"com/my/company/utils/Formatter"], function (..., Formatter) {
"use strict";

return Controller.extend("com.my.company.View", {
```

View.view.xml

```
<GenericTag status="{path: 'MyStatus', formatter: 'com.my.company.utils.Formatter.myFormatter'}/>
```