# How to have control instance as "this" in formatter?

Tags: sapui5

I am using SAP UI5 1.52. My formatter file is a separate file and loaded in the controller. But logging `this` in the formatter returns view instance rather than control instance.

I have referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32222703/5846045) before and tried using absolute path and changed the way object is returned in formatter. It throws an error saying function not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## UI5 1.69+

### View

```xml
<MyControl xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" core:require="{ format: 'demo/model/format' }"
  property="{
    path: '...',
    formatter: 'format'
  }"
/><!-- Note: remove the dot (.) in front of the formatter function name -->
```

### Formatter

```js
sap.ui.define([], function() { // location: "demo/model/format.js"
  "use strict";

  return function(data) {
    // this === control instance
  };
});
```

As of UI5 1.69, we can [*require modules directly in the view definition*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/b11d853a8e784db6b2d210ef57b0f7d7). Requiring and assigning the formatter directly in the binding info lets us to use `this` as the corresponding control instance.

The documentation mentions it as well:

- From the [API reference `sap/ui/base/ManagedObject#bindProperty`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#methods/bindProperty):

  > When the formatter for a property binding (simple or composite) is called, the managed object will be given as `this` context
- From the topic [*Property Binding*](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070):

  > The `this` context of a formatter function is generally set to the
  > control (or managed object) that owns the binding.

Answer (score -2):

In a control's property, you typically write `formatter:'.formatter.functionName'`

Just change it to: `formatter:'namespace.controllerFolder.controllerName.prototype.formatter.functionName'`

And `this` will now refer to the control instance rather than your controller.

Simple and easy :)